# Find out which element was clicked from the list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few divs that share the same class.
I have a dropdown that changes the background color of one of those divs when selected(option 2 changes div #2).
My question is how can I change the dropdown option when clicking a certain div?
I have the logic behind changing the actual option and the div clicks, but I can't figure out how to find exactly which of the divs was clicked(the divs are dynamically created, so they don't have Ids, only class names).
Is there any way to check what div was clicked relatively to the entire list of divs with the same class?
  Thanks.
Example code:

```
<select class="size form-control" id="size" name="size">
<option value="1">first div</option>
<option value="2">second div</option>
<option value="4">third div..</option>
</select>

<div class="collection">random</div>
<div class="collection">text</div>
<div class="collection">inside</div>
<div class="collection">here</div>
```

Edit:
What I have:
The select can change the color of a div depending on choice.
Clicking a div changes it's own color.
What I need:
Clicking a div also changes the option in the select.
I hope it's a bit clearer now

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: You can get the targeted element by using `$(this)` inside the event handler.

Comment: how about showing your html and code? [ask]

Comment: dynamically created `div`s can have `id`s if you add them

Comment: Try **jQuery** `event.target` [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: Need to see the "background color change" function as well....

Comment: ^ Not relevant to the question. The background function can be whatever. I am looking for a way to get the index of the clicked div when looking by class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With jQuery You can get the index of the clicked div by using [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$('div.collection').click(function () {
    var index = $('div.collection').index($(this));
    console.log(index);

    $('select').val(index + 1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collection">Div1</div>
<div class="collection">Div2</div>
<div class="collection">Div3</div>
<div class="collection">Div4</div>

<select class="size form-control" id="size" name="size">
    <option value="1">first div</option>
    <option value="2">second div</option>
    <option value="4">third div..</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also make it DRY: `var index = $(this).index();`

Comment: ^ Unfortunately that doesn't produce the needed result as the divs are dynamic(their amount can and will change).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for this, It's very simple:

```
<select class="size form-control" id="size" name="size">
  <option value="1">first div</option>
  <option value="2">second div</option>
  <option value="4">third div..</option>
</select>

<div class="collection">Div1</div>
<div class="collection">Div2</div>
<div class="collection">Div3</div>
<div class="collection">Div4</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div.collection').click(function(){
var index = $('div.collection').index($(this)) + 1;
  $('select').val(index);
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/zBgvJr

Comment: Works just like what Kld wrote, just a minute too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the div around a parent div and use `index()` to get the position of div

```js
$('.collection').click(function(){
  var position = $(this).index()+1;
  console.log(position);
  $('.size').val(position);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="size form-control" id="size" name="size">
<option value="1">first div</option>
<option value="2">second div</option>
<option value="3">third div..</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth div..</option>
</select>
<div>
  <div class="collection">random</div>
  <div class="collection">text</div>
  <div class="collection">inside</div>
  <div class="collection">here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Pen](http://codepen.io/vaibhavsah/pen/JKgYxQ) .

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
   <div class="clickMe">1</div>
   <div class="clickMe">2</div>
   <div class="clickMe">3</div>
   <div class="clickMe">4</div>
</div>
<select name="dropDown">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<style>
.clickMe{
  clear:both;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#parentDiv').on('click','.clickMe',function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
      var index= $(this).index();
      $('select[name=dropDown] option:eq('+index+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Thanks. Please tell if it works fine.